# Postback method not triggered with jQuery Validate

Tags: asp.net, jquery, jquery-validate, validation

I have a strange behaviour of my jQuery Validate script.

I have a simple form with a submit button (ID = _btnSave).
I validate three text fields : firstname, lastname and email.

[NOT WORKING] - When the form is filled in correctly, the method on my submit button is not fired : OnClick="_btnSave_Click".

[WORKING] - I write down a wrong email address, then I correct it, click on the submit button, my server-side method is called.

To summarize the situation : If I don't trigger the validation of the email, _btnSave_Click is not fired.

The page is refreshed in both cases.

```
<asp:Button ID="_btnSave" OnClick="_btnSave_Click" CssClass="button big default" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:Resource, SAVE_CHANGES %>" />
```

---

```
$("#form1").validate({
            rules:{
                <%=_txtEmail.UniqueID %>:{ minlength:5, required:true, email:true, 
                    remote: { 
                        url: "/Services/ValidatorService.asmx/ValidateEmail",
                        dataType:"json",
                        type:"post",
                        data: { 
                            email: function() { return $("#<%=_txtEmail.ClientID%>").val();},
                            contactUID: function() { return $("#<%=_hidContactUID.ClientID%>").val();}
                        }
                    }
                },
                <%=_txtFirstName.UniqueID %>:   { required:true},
                <%=_txtLastName.UniqueID %>:    { required:true},
            },
            invalidHandler: function(form, validator) {
                errorContainer.fadeIn(); 
            },
            errorElement: "span",
            errorClass:"errortxt",
            highlight: function(element, errorClass) {
                $(element).parent().parent().addClass("error");
            },
            unhighlight: function(element, errorClass) { 
                    $(element).parent().parent().removeClass("error");
                if (this.numberOfInvalids() == 0) { 
                    errorContainer.fadeOut(); 
                }
            },
            messages: { <%=_txtEmail.UniqueID %>: { remote : "<%=EmailUsed %>" }
            },
            errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                    error.insertAfter(element);
            }
        });

        $("input").click(function(){_defaultButton = $("#<%=_btnSave.ClientID%>");});   
    });
```

Thanks for your help.

Greg

Comment: I think you should be using ClientID instead of UniqueID, though you should be having more serious problems than that. What is the overall situation? Any UpdatePanels involved? What does you submit control look like?

Comment: Hi jamietre, I'm using ClientID. No UpdatePanel, the validation is working perfectly. The code of the button is described in the first code block.

Answer (score 3):

I know this question is old, but I was experiencing the same problem recently and could not find an answer online. Adding a custom submit handler in the validator options fixed the problem for me:

```
        $("#form1").validate({
            submitHandler: function (form) {
                __doPostBack("_btnSave", "OnClick");
            }
            // your other options
        });
```